# Linear regression in Numpy that takes account of data point standard deviations

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression, curve-fitting

Importing the libraries needed:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

I have the df

```
volfit=pd.DataFrame({'Osmolarity':[100,200,300,400,600,800],'avgvol':[1.27,1.06,1,0.92,0.84,0.74],'stdev':[0.132,0.053,0,0.037,0.040,0.077]})
```

fitting the data below:

```
p,cov=np.polyfit(volfit['Osmolarity'], volfit['avgvol'],1,cov=True)
slope=p[0]
intercept=p[1]
std_err=np.sqrt(np.diag(cov))
slope_std_err= std_err[0]
int_std_err = std_err[1]
```

plotting the fit below:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(5,4))
plt.scatter(volfit['Osmolarity'], volfit['avgvol'],color="black")
plt.plot(volfit['Osmolarity'],np.polyval(p,volfit['Osmolarity']),color='red')
plt.errorbar(volfit['Osmolarity'], volfit['avgvol'],yerr=volfit['stdev'],ls='none',color='black')
plt.title('y={:.4f}x + {:.1f} \nslope \u03C3 \u00B1 {:.4f} \n  b-int \u03C3 \u00B1 {:.2f}'.format(slope, intercept,slope_std_err,int_std_err),size=18,horizontalalignment='center',x=0.6, y=0.6)
ax.set_xlabel("\u03A0 (mOsm)",size=18)
ax.set_ylabel(r'Cell Volume Change ($\tilde{v}$)',size=18)
```

And I get this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa4Cv.png) . What I want to do is use the standard deviations to force the polyfit to consider the points with the lowest standard deviations more than the ones with the really high standard deviations. So I would want the plot to look like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vKCD.png) where it crosses through (300,1) because it has the an stdev of 0.

Comment: I don't think np.polyfit will do what you want, but [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) can. If you have the data that gave rise to each standard deviation though, why not just do the linear regression on the whole of that dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the kwarg `w = weights`. Then you have to choose how you want your weights to depend on the standard deviation, a simple choice would be

```
coeff, cov = np.polyfit(x, y, 1, cov=True, w=(1/sigma))
```

Such that the weight is inversely proportional to the standard deviation, then set the std. dev. of (300, 1) to 1e-16 or some other small, non-zero number.

Edit: A quite common "hack" to use if you have a single point that you **know** that your fit **has** to pass through to be physically meaningful is to just add a bunch of points there. That is: Just add 100 or 1000 or some large enough number of copies of the point at (300, 1) to the data-set to force it to go through that point.